# How to get the default value of a column of MS Access Database using C++?

Tags: c++, ado

This is the sql script I used to create a table in MS Access Database.

```
CREATE TABLE Contracts (
id int  NULL DEFAULT 0,
sex varchar(255) DEFAULT 'female' NOT NULL
)
```

Now I want to programmatically get the default value of the field: "sex", I know it's 'female' but I don't know how to get it using C++ ADO interface.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
m_pRecordset->Fields->get_Item(vIntegerType, &pvObject);
bstrColName = pvObject->GetName();
dtype = pvObject->GetType();
attr = pvObject->GetAttributes();
```

Comment: Your normally use `gender` rather than `sex`... and I would definitely not use a varchar(255) for the job (unless you plan on having a very great variety I guess)

Answer (score 0):

I can give you idea how to achieve it..

**GetAttributes()** method will not give you default value of the field but it will give you info about whether field is autoincrement ,system field or fixed - variable size field.

Check out for method **GetDefaultValue()** of the field that will do what you want.

Comment: Hi, Fields has no **GetDefaultValue()** method at all.